# Zip ruby killing file content

Tags: ruby, zip

I am working on zipping the file (Ruby 1.8.6 which can not change) from the folders. Now Earlier had less lines in the file which was zipping fine. But when I add more content to zip , It gives me file which looks like corrupt content. This is the sort view of the long file. Files having more the 5000 lines.

Is there any way to zip the full content without corrupting .

Content like

```
Family = 1,1,1
```

is now `Fam`

Here is a code with Class

```
 def download
    FileUtils.rm_rf Dir.glob("#{RAILS_ROOT}/#{params[:id]}/xx.zip")
    zip_them_all = ZipThemAll.new("#{RAILS_ROOT}/#{params[:id]}/xxx.zip","#{RAILS_ROOT}/#{params[:id]}/")
    zip_them_all.zip
 end

class ZipThemAll
    attr_accessor :list_of_file_paths, :zip_file_path
    def initialize( zip_file_path, list_of_file_paths )
        @zip_file_path = zip_file_path
        list_of_file_paths = [list_of_file_paths] if list_of_file_paths.class == String
        @list_of_file_paths = list_of_file_paths
    end

    def zip
        zip_file = Zip::ZipFile.open(self.zip_file_path, Zip::ZipFile::CREATE)
        self.zip_em_all( zip_file, @list_of_file_paths )
        zip_file.close
    end

    def zip_em_all( zip_file, file_list, sub_directory=nil )
        file_list.each do | file_path |
            if File.exists?file_path
                if File.directory?( file_path )
                    file_directory_list = []
                    # Find.find( file_path ) do | path |
                    file_directory_list = Dir.entries( file_path )
                    file_directory_list.delete(".")
                    file_directory_list.delete("..")
                    file_directory_list = file_directory_list.inject([]) do | result, path |
                        result << file_path + "/" + path
                        result
                    end
                    self.zip_em_all( zip_file, file_directory_list, (sub_directory == nil ? '.' : sub_directory) + "/" + File.basename(file_path) )
                else
                    file_name = File.basename( file_path )
                    if sub_directory != nil
                        if zip_file.find_entry( sub_directory ) == nil
                            dir = zip_file.mkdir( sub_directory )
                        end
                        file_name = sub_directory + "/" + file_name
                    end
                    if zip_file.find_entry( file_name )
                        zip_file.replace( file_name, file_path )
                    else
                        zip_file.add( file_name, file_path)
                    end
                end
            else
                puts "Warning: file #{file_path} does not exist"
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: I am getting all the files also , but the some of the files get corrupted and does not provide the full content

Answer (score 1):

Please don't interpolate params directly into paths.

This allows malicious users to navigate your system arbitrarily.

[image: Bobby Tables].